# Need help with understanding the problem

Tags: number-theory

I don’t understand the formulation of the following problem:

We call a natural number $b$ "happy" if for every natural number $a$ such that $a^5$ is divisible by $b^2$ it follows that $a^2$ is divisible by $b$. How many "happy" numbers below $2018$ are there.

My confusion is, isn’t this true for all $a$,  $b$?

N.B. do *NOT* give a solution, only help with the formulation.

Thank you

Comment: It is true that if $a$ is a multiple of $b$ then both statements are true, but that's not what the question asks.

Comment: $a^5$ being a multiple of $b^2$ does not imply that $a$ is a multiple of $b$.  Ex.  Let $a=p^2$ and $b=p^5$ then $a^5 =p^{10}=b^2$ but $b=p^5\not\mid p^4=a^2$.  So no $p^5$ is happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just overthinking the problem statement. Who cares if it works for any number that is a multiple of $b$? That will contribute to the count of the number of happy numbers below 2018, but that has nothing to do with the problem formulation.

Someone deleted a comment that I think is relevant, and that is to try a computational example:

Let $b=3$. Then if $a^5$ is divisible by $9$, $a^5$ is divisible by $3$, and thus $a$ is divisible by $3$, and thus $a^2$ is divisible by $3$. This makes $b$ happy.

However, if $b=3^5$, and $a=3^2$, then $a^5=3^{10}$ is divisible by $b^2=3^{10}$, but $a^2=3^4$ is not divisible by $b$.

Comment: Yes but I want to find them without programming.

Comment: @MathFanatics But you wanted no solution (with or without programming), only a help with the formulation.

Comment: I didn’t understand what they ment with the implication. Isn’t the implication true for all b?

Comment: @MathFanatics I have added an explicit example of both a happy number and an unhappy number to help clarify the formulation.

Comment: But can’t you then just choose b=1,2,..,2018?

Comment: Ah, okey. I think I understand now. Thank you

Comment: @MathFanatics We have just shown that not all $b$ are happy. In particular, it would seem that 5th powers of primes are all unhappy, but we have also (basically) shown that all primes are happy. You are going to be forced at some step to actually list these numbers out in order to count them, so I think that programming is almost certainly expected. Maybe we can make our programs fast with clever math, but I don't know the number of primes less than 2018 off the top of my head.